# What is the best way to implement user LIVE status tracking on my website?

Tags: php, user-tracking

I am thinking of creating a micro service for my own website, that will allow me to know at any moment in time, whether the user is LIVE on the website, meaning that he/she is logged in, and the tab is active in the browser. I am totally new to the topic, so I would appreciate a good suggestion on what would be the best way to implement such functionality. The main requirements are that the failure of the service shouldn't affect the normal website functionality or increase the traffic significantly. I am considering using PHP for the task, but there is still some flexibility, if there is some better technology. I would really appreciate the advice on that!

Comment: read about websockets

Comment: Thank you, @Vidal, for the suggestion! I am already researching this possibility, and it seems to fit the purpose, but I still cannot find any info on when does the connection close on its own, or does it? Cause my initial idea was to also keep track of whether the user has switched from the tab, so I've been wondering, if that is tracked somehow. I would appreciate if you could explain this point, cause I believe that I might be misunderstanding the concept

Comment: you can track the mouse movement on your page, if it does not move in X time then we can assume that he is away.

Comment: @Vidal, okay, got it, thanks for the suggestion!